# dot42 jar import is missing methods

Tags: android, dot42

I imported a jar project in to my dot42 project. It appears to have made a wrapper but it is missing some methods. Any idea what I am doing wrong? The jar is this one:

[usb-serial-for-android](https://code.google.com/p/usb-serial-for-android/)

It creates the wrapper for UsbSerialProber but the definition is missing the 'aquire' method:

```
    public sealed class UsbSerialProber
    {
            /// <java-name>
            /// FTDI_SERIAL
            /// </java-name>
            [Dot42.JavaImport("FTDI_SERIAL", "Lcom/hoho/android/usbserial/driver/UsbSerialProber;", AccessFlags = 16409)]
            public static readonly global::Com.Hoho.Android.Usbserial.Driver.UsbSerialProber FTDI_SERIAL;
            /// <java-name>
            /// CDC_ACM_SERIAL
            /// </java-name>
            [Dot42.JavaImport("CDC_ACM_SERIAL", "Lcom/hoho/android/usbserial/driver/UsbSerialProber;", AccessFlags = 16409)]
            public static readonly global::Com.Hoho.Android.Usbserial.Driver.UsbSerialProber CDC_ACM_SERIAL;
            private extern UsbSerialProber();

    }
```

Comment: https://github.com/dot42/dot42/issues/7

Comment: This is a bug in the 'import jar' module which generates C# proxies for the java types.

Answer (score 0):

The UsbSerialProber is a Java enum with methods which is not supported by C#. To map this to C#, we treat it as a class. Unfortunately, in doing so, all methods were removed. This has been fixed in 1.0.81.0 which is now available for download.